# Solr: ignore or modify fields with incorrect type or other type errors

Tags: solr

I am reading hundreds of thousands of documents into a Solr instance using the `post` tool. I've found that out of this corpus, about 150 documents failed due to some type of schema type error e.g. I defined a field "created" as a date field, but a few documents had an invalid date value in that field.

Rather than changing the schema and reindexing all the documents (a process that takes about 20 hours), for my purposes it is fine to just read the documents that failed into the index by ignoring the "created" field.

How can I configure Solr to ingest the documents it receives and simply drop the `created` field from them? Even better, how can I tell Solr to simply drop *any* field which fails schema validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

## 1) Ignore the Field

To ignore the field in question, use the [`fmap` parameter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika) to map it to an ignored field. For example:

```
bin/post -c mycollection -params \
    "fmap.created=ignored_created" files...
```

which leverages the dynamic `ignored_*` field of type `ignored` in the schema e.g.:

```
<dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
```

## 2) Change the Format

If the information is valid but not in the correct format, use an update processor to parse the format, or to modify the input. For example, to parse dates in an unusual format, add the format to the `solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory` in `solrconfig.xml`.

To modify the input, use a [`RegexReplaceProcessorFactory`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_3_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/RegexReplaceProcessorFactory.html).